# How to catch WM_DEVICECHANGE in a control other than TForm?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, windows-messages

Until today I was using the following code to catch `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message in application main form and it worked pefectly. But if I try to use this in my custom control I don't get notifyed on device insert or remove. What is happening ?

```
  TDriveBar = class(TCustomPanel)
  private
    procedure WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_DEVICECHANGE;  
  end;

implementation

procedure TDriveBar.WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage);
const DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = $8000;
      DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = $8004;
      DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME = 2;

type PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR = ^DEV_BROADCAST_HDR;
     DEV_BROADCAST_HDR = record
      dbch_size: dword;
      dbch_devicetype: dword;
      dbch_reserved: dword;
     end;

begin
 case Msg.WParam of

  DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
   if PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(Msg.LParam)^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then UpdateDrives;

  DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
   if PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(Msg.LParam)^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then UpdateDrives;

 end;
end;
```

Comment: [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431(v=vs.85).aspx) for your control.

Comment: `RegisterDeviceNotification` Is the only solution ? Why my code doesn't work ?

Comment: why should it work? if you did not allocated memory, can you use it? if you did not opened file, can you write into it? if you did not asked for notifications, why you would ever get them?

here is pure Win API - you can see it is REQUIRED to ask windows for keep you updated

http://www.cyberforum.ru/win-api/thread987978.html

Comment: Marus, read the first paragraphs at #2 google result for WM_DEVICECHANGE : 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363215.aspx

Comment: Ok, but if someone cand help me with an complete answer showing how to use the register function, because I don't understand what parameters should I pass...

Comment: you can see the class using this procedure at http://www.delphikingdom.com/asp/answer.asp?IDAnswer=38565 

you can also install JediVCL and check TJvDeviceChanged and TJvHidDeviceController components

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OS sends `wm_DeviceChange` messages to all top-level windows. The application's main form is a top-level window, but your control is not, which is why the form receives the messages and your control does not.

For arbitrary device types, you have two alternatives:

1. Use [`AllocateHWnd`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.AllocateHWnd) to create a message-only top-level window that will respond to messages by calling a function associated with your control. This will give you the same basic information as the main form receives.

   Write a method for your control that matches the signature for `TWndMethod`, which is what `AllocateHWnd` requires. It might look like this:

   ```
   procedure TDriveBar.DeviceWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
   begin
     case Message.Msg of
       wm_DeviceChange: begin
         case Message.WParam of
           DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
             if PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(Message.LParam).dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then
               UpdateDrives;
         end;
       end;
     end;
     Message.Result := DefWindowProc(FDeviceWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
   end;
   ```

   Then use that method when you create the message window:

   ```
   FDeviceWnd := AllocateHWnd(DeviceWindowProc);
   ```
2. Call [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) to tell the OS that your control's window wants to receive notifications, too. (Make sure you handle your control's `CreateWnd` and `DestroyWnd` methods so that if your control is re-created, you renew the notification registration with the control's new window handle.) This will give you more detailed information than the default `wm_DeviceChange` message provides, but only for the kinds of devices you specify when you register your window handle.

However, you're interested in changes to **volumes**. The remarks for `RegisterDeviceNotification` have something to say about that (emphasis added):

> The `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` events are automatically broadcast to all top-level windows for port devices. Therefore, it is not necessary to call `RegisterDeviceNotification` for ports, and the function fails if the `dbch_devicetype` member is `DBT_DEVTYP_PORT`. **Volume notifications are also broadcast to top-level windows, so the function fails if `dbch_devicetype` is `DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME`.**

That eliminates that notification registration as an option for you, so the only solution in your case is to use `AllocateHWnd`.

Comment: Yes, the first option (with AllocateHWnd) works perfectly. Thanks !

Comment: @MarusNebunu Also...don't forget to close your notification handles when you are done.  When your component is destroyed, be sure to call `UnregisterDeviceNotification`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363475.aspx

Comment: You are right, but I used the first option so I suppose I should call `DeallocateHWnd(FDeviceWnd)`.

Comment: Yes, Marus, @J... Whichever method is right for you, this answer is not a substitute for the documentation. Release whatever resources you acquire, and in the way the documentation tells you to do it.