# Why I don't receive messages in my control when I use "message" directive?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, message

When my control is created I must use `DeviceWnd:=AllocateHWnd(DeviceWindowProc);` to receive `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message. And then...

```
procedure TFileList.DeviceWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  case Message.Msg of
    WM_DEVICECHANGE: begin
      case Message.WParam of
        DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
          if PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(Message.LParam).dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then
           OnDeviceChange;
      end;
    end;
  end; 
  Message.Result:=DefWindowProc(DeviceWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

This works well, but why I don't reveive that message when I do like this ? :

```
TFileList = class(TCustomControl)
private
  procedure DeviceChage(var AMessage:TMessage); message WM_DEVICECHANGE;
end;

procedure TFileList.DeviceWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result:=DefWindowProc(DeviceWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;

procedure TFileList.DeviceChage(var AMessage:TMessage);
begin
 case AMessage.WParam of
   DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
     if PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(AMessage.LParam).dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then
       OnDeviceChange;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: Have you used `RegisterDeviceNotification` ? You have to, because `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message is broadcasted only to the top level windows.

Comment: No, the message is received very well without `RegisterDeviceNotification`, but not reveived when I usee "message" directive.

Comment: @MarusNebunu: pay attention to what TLama said. `WM_DEVICECHANGE` is only broadcasted to **top-level** windows by default.  Your control is NOT a top-level window, `AllocateHWnd()` is. If the control wants the message, it has to use `RegisterDeviceNotification()` to ask for it.

Comment: I already told you [the last time you asked about this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30712485/33732): "The OS sends `wm_DeviceChange` messages to all top-level windows. The application's main form is a top-level window, but your control is not, which is why the form receives the messages and your control does not."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx):

> Applications send event notifications using the BroadcastSystemMessage function. Any application with a top-level window can receive basic notifications by processing the WM_DEVICECHANGE message. Applications can use the RegisterDeviceNotification function to register to receive device notifications.

The window that you create with `AllocateHWnd` is a top-level window. Hence it receives the broadcast messages.

Your custom control is not a top level window. If you want it to receive messages you will have to call `RegisterDeviceNotification` passing its window handle. If you do that, be sure to deal with VCL window recreation by registering in `CreateWnd` and unregistering in `DestroyWnd`.

As a general rule of thumb, `AllocateHwnd` is the preferred way to listen for notifications. That's because it is not subject to VCL window recreation, and so cannot miss notifications. When a VCL window is being recreated then there is a window of opportunity for notifications to be sent, but your application not having a window ready to receive.

That's certainly going to be an issue in your case and so you should use `AllocateHwnd`. You can arrange that the window you create with `AllocateHwnd` is owned by your custom control, and then you can route the notification to that control's code.

Comment: But I created a top level window for my control when I use the "message" directive...

Comment: No, that's not what a top level window is. Your main form is a top level window. Child windows, like your custom control, are not. The window allocated by `AllocateHwnd` is a top level window.

Comment: If I use `procedure DeviceChage(var AMessage:TMessage); message WM_DEVICECHANGE;` in my control, this procedure is not attached to the top leve window created with `AllocateHwnd` ? if not, who is attached to?

Comment: That's associated with the class in which it is defined. Since that class, your custom control, is windowed, then it is called from the window procedure of the window behind your custom control.

Comment: You seem to have two windows now: `DeviceWnd` which is top-level and its associated window procedure is `TFileList.DeviceWindowProc` which does receive `WM_DEVICECHANGE` but does nothing in response, and `TFileList.Handle` which is not top-level, therefore it doesn't receive `WM_DEVICECHANGE`.

Comment: So, that call to `DefWindowProc` form the `DeviceWindowProc` doesn't mean that it's called the control default not top level window procedure ?

Comment: @MarusNebunu: No, `DefWindowProc()` simply means that *any* message that your procedure *happens* to receive will be passed to the OS for default processing.

Comment: @MarusNebunu: To do what you are attempting, you MUST have your custom control either 1) call `AllocateHwnd()` specifying `DeviceChange()` (without the `message` directive) or `DeviceWindowProc()` as its wndproc, or 2) override `CreateWnd()` and `DestroyWnd()` to call `RegisterDeviceChange()` with its own `Handle` as the recipient, then `DeviceChange()` (with the `message`directive) can receive the message, or override `WndProc()` directly.

Answer (score 2):

`WM_DEVICECHANGE` is broadcasted to top-level windows.  Your custom control's window is not a top-level window, it is a child window of the control's `Parent` window.  That is why your `message` handler is not being called - the message is never arriving in your control's `WndProc()` so it can be dispatched to a `message` handler.

For most device notifications, you can use [`RegisterDeviceNotification()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) to have `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages be sent to a specific `HWND`.  However, in your example, **volume** change messages cannot be registered like that:

> the function fails if dbch_devicetype is **DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME**.

So, for your custom control to receive `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages, it MUST allocate its own top-level window, such as with the `AllocateHwnd()` function:

```
type
  // TCustomControl is meant to be used for developing **visual**
  // controls. If your custom control is not visual, you should
  // derive from `TComponent` instead...
  TFileList = class(TCustomControl)
  private
    DeviceWnd: HWND;
    procedure DeviceWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
  public
    constructor Create(Owner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TFileList.Create(Owner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(Owner);
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    DeviceWnd := AllocateHwnd(DeviceWindowProc);
end;

destructor TFileList.Destroy;
begin
  if DeviceWnd <> 0 then
    DeallocateHwnd(DeviceWnd);
  inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TFileList.DeviceWindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  if Message.Msg = WM_DEVICECHANGE then
  begin
    case Message.WParam of
      DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        if PDEV_BROADCAST_HDR(Message.LParam).dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME then
          OnDeviceChange;
    end;
  end;
  Message.Result := DefWindowProc(DeviceWnd, Message.Msg, Message.WParam, Message.LParam);
end;
```

Comment: I can't use the second option. David explains here why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711942/how-to-catch-wm-devicechange-in-a-control-other-than-tform

Comment: Excuse me, Marus. I think if you look again you'll see it was *I* who explained, not David.

Comment: Indeed, the answer it's yours. You must excuse me. I was misleaded by David's edit.